# Teclado bugando imagem no android [IONIC 2]

Tags: ionic, formulário, login, ionic2, ionic3

estou com o seguinte problema: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver na imagem acima, quando eu clico para escrever nos campos de login e senha, aparece esse fundo branco na imagem.

Imagino que o problema esteja relacionado com o teclado do android, já que no IOS funciona normalmente e não aparece nada de anormal.

Alguém já viu esse erro antes? Tem ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insira esse CSS na pagina em que isso esta acontecendo:

> .scroll-content {
>       padding-bottom: 0 !important;
>    }